# How to fix this ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core.toolcmd'

Tags: python-3.x

When I run project, I have error: `ModuleNotFoundError`: No module named `core.toolcmd`

```
import sys
import argparse
import subprocess
import os
import time
import random
import threading
import re
import random
from urllib.parse import urlsplit
from core.toolcmd import *
from core.toolfix import *
from core.toolnames import *
from core.toolprecheck import *
from core.toolresp import *
from core.toolstatus import *
from plugins.banner import BannerFunction
from plugins.colors import *
```

I try pip3 install core.toolscmd but show me error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement `core.toolcmd` (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for `core.toolcmd`
```